# Is there a better way to write this Show/hide JQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

Ok, I finally got it to work the way I want it too.

I needed it to have different buttons for show/hide and to hide if another DIV is asked to be shown, also I needed to place my a tags away from my DIV tags as well as add and remove the class active. But, even though it works, I know it's really messy.

Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/qKWC8/24/

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Feature box 1

    $('#show1').click(function() {
        $('#show2,#show3,#show4,#show5,#show6').removeClass("active");
        $("#feature-2,#feature-3,#feature-4,#feature-5,#feature-6").hide();
        $("#feature-1").show();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('#hide1').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('#show1').removeClass("active");
    });

    // Feature box 2

    $('#show2').click(function() {
        $('#show1,#show3,#show4,#show5,#show6').removeClass("active");
        $("#feature-1,#feature-3,#feature-4,#feature-5,#feature-6").hide();
        $("#feature-2").show();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('#hide2').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('#show2').removeClass("active");
    });

    // Feature box 3

    $('#show3').click(function() {
        $('#show1,#show2,#show4,#show5,#show6').removeClass("active");
        $("#feature-1,#feature-2,#feature-4,#feature-5,#feature-6").hide();
        $("#feature-3").show();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('#hide3').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('#show3').removeClass("active");
    });

    // Feature box 4

    $('#show4').click(function() {
       $('#show1,#show2,#show3,#show5,#show6').removeClass("active");
        $("#feature-1,#feature-2,#feature-3,#feature-5,#feature-6").hide();
        $("#feature-4").show();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('#hide4').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('#show4').removeClass("active");
    });

    // Feature box 5

    $('#show5').click(function() {
       $('#show1,#show2,#show3,#show4,#show6').removeClass("active");
        $("#feature-1,#feature-2,#feature-3,#feature-4,#feature-6").hide();
        $("#feature-5").show();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('#hide5').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('#show5').removeClass("active");
    });

    // Feature box 6

    $('#show6').click(function() {
       $('#show1,#show2,#show3,#show4,#show5').removeClass("active");
        $("#feature-1,#feature-2,#feature-3,#feature-4,#feature-5").hide();
        $("#feature-6").show();
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('#hide6').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('#show6').removeClass("active");
        });
    });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="show1">Show</a>
<a href="#" id="show2">Show</a>
<a href="#" id="show3">Show</a>
<a href="#" id="show4">Show</a>
<a href="#" id="show5">Show</a>
<a href="#" id="show6">Show</a>

<div id="feature-1">
    Fill this space with really interesting content 1. <a href="#" id="hide1">Hide</a>
</div>

<div id="feature-2">
    Fill this space with really interesting content 2. <a href="#" id="hide2">Hide</a>
</div>


<div id="feature-3">
    Fill this space with really interesting content 3. <a href="#" id="hide3">Hide</a>
</div>

<div id="feature-4">
    Fill this space with really interesting content 4. <a href="#" id="hide4">Hide</a>
</div>

<div id="feature-5">
    Fill this space with really interesting content 5. <a href="#" id="hide5">Hide</a>
</div>

<div id="feature-6">
    Fill this space with really interesting content 6. <a href="#" id="hide6">Hide</a>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#feature-1,#feature-2,#feature-3,#feature-4,#feature-5,#feature-6 {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
    display: none;
}
.active{background:#00FFFF;}
```

Comment: So, each of those blocks is the same except for what? The number indicating the div in question. Any way you could take advantage of that information?

Comment: can you use http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's almost always a better way... ;)

**JavaScript:**

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#links a").click(function(){
        $(".feature").hide();
        $("#features div").eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
    $("a.hide").click(function(){
        $(this).parent("div").hide();
    });
});
```

**HTML:** (I slightly changed your HTML structure)

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="#">Show</a>
    <a href="#">Show</a>
    ...
</div>

<div id="features">
    <div class="feature">
        Fill this space with really interesting content 1. <a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        Fill this space with really interesting content 2. <a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

[**DEMO** (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/R9jZc/)

Comment: Works great! How does it know which a tag is assigned to which DIV?

Comment: The code uses indices. So when you click e.g. the fourth link in `div#links`, the fourth `.feature` container in `div#features` will be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use classes instead of the IDs. Based on your current markup, I have minified your code, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a[id^=show]').click(function() {
        var which = this.id.slice(-1);
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings('a').removeClass("active");
        $("div[id^='feature']").hide();
        $("#feature-"+which).show();
    });

    $('a[id^=hide]').click(function() {
        var which = this.id.slice(-1);
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('#show'+which).removeClass("active");
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKWC8/26/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('show1','feature-1')" class="anchors" id="show1">Show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('show2','feature-2')" class="anchors" id="show2">Show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('show3','feature-3')" class="anchors" id="show3">Show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('show4','feature-4')" class="anchors" id="show4">Show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('show5','feature-5')" class="anchors" id="show5">Show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('show6','feature-6')" class="anchors" id="show6">Show</a>

<div class="features" id="feature-1">
Fill this space with really interesting content 1. <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">Hide</a>
</div>

<div class="features"  id="feature-2">
Fill this space with really interesting content 2. <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">Hide</a>
</div>


<div class="features" id="feature-3">
Fill this space with really interesting content 3. <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">Hide</a>
</div>

<div class="features" id="feature-4">
Fill this space with really interesting content 4. <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">Hide</a>
</div>

<div class="features" id="feature-5">
Fill this space with really interesting content 5. <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">Hide</a>
</div>

<div class="features" id="feature-6">
Fill this space with really interesting content 6. <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().hide();">Hide</a>
</div>
/// javascript

function myfunction(anchor_id, feature_id){
 $('.anchors').removeClass("active");
    $(".features").hide();
    $("#"+feature_id).show();
    $("#"+anchor_id).addClass("active");
}
```

i have minimize some of your JS code hope so it will be helpful for you